# How to replace the comma with a space when I use the "MultiAutoCompleteTextView"

Tags: android, android-widget, multiautocompletetextview

I'm doing a simple program using `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` to prompt the common words when I input several letters.

code:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, 
            ary);
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    textView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    private String[] ary = new String[] {
       "abc",
       "abcd",
       "abcde",
       "abcdef",
       "abcdefg",
       "hij",
       "hijk",
       "hijkl",
       "hijklm",
       "hijklmn",
    };
```

Now,when I input *'a'* and choose *"abcd"* but the result become to "abcd,". How to replace the comma with a space?

Thank you!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
public class SpaceTokenizer implements Tokenizer {

public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
int i = cursor;

while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ') {
    i--;
}
while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
    i++;
}

return i;
}

public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
int i = cursor;
int len = text.length();

while (i < len) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        return i;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}

return len;
}

public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
int i = text.length();

while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
    i--;
}

if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
    return text;
} else {
    if (text instanceof Spanned) {
        SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
        TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                Object.class, sp, 0);
        return sp;
    } else {
        return text + " ";
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Comment: In `findTokenStart`, you iterate backward, then forward .... looks like once? Why do this?

Comment: you should probably use Character.isWhitespace instead of comparing to ' ' this way it works with newlines and tabs etc

Comment: Where to call class ?

Comment: Call it like this mactv.setTokenizer(new SpaceTokenizer());

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it would be to implement your own [Tokenizer](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer.html).  The reason the comma comes up is because you're using [CommaTokenizer](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer.html), which is designed to do exactly that.  You can also look at [the source code for CommaTokenizer](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.java;hb=HEAD) if you need a reference for how to implement your own SpaceTokenizer.

Comment: oh,thank you.
But when I include the "MultiAutoCompleteTextView.java",I encounter an error "com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved",and I cann't find this file...

Comment: Tokenizer link is broken.

Comment: @Daniel, Can you update the link for source code of tokenizer? link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Check my question/answer

[How to replace MultiAutoCompleteTextView drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209339/how-to-replace-multiautocompletetextview-drop-down-list)

you will find a SpaceTokenizer class

Comment: Is it possible to implement this without using tokenizers ? I mean for example if i do not want any comma or space as tokenizers then will the spannable functionality work as it is ?

Comment: You can change separator value with any character that you want. Don't know the reason why you don't want to user tokenizer, but you can remove tokenizer instance if you want.

Comment: I changed to space tokenizer, but if my striings (in multi auto complete text view) already contain spaces .e.g. person name, then do I need to take some other tokenizer OR space will work fine in this scneario too ?

Comment: In that case SpaceTokenizer wont work. You must implement your own tokenizer with a more clever behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Kotlin for a white space tokenizer. This also caters tabs, trailing spaces and line feeds.

```
object : Tokenizer {
            override fun findTokenStart(text: CharSequence, cursor: Int): Int {
                val spaceIndex = text.indexOfFirst { Character.isWhitespace(it) }
                return if (spaceIndex > cursor)
                    spaceIndex
                else cursor
            }

            override fun findTokenEnd(text: CharSequence, cursor: Int): Int {
                val lastSpaceIndex = text.indexOfLast { Character.isWhitespace(it) }
                return if (lastSpaceIndex > cursor)
                    lastSpaceIndex
                else cursor
            }

            override fun terminateToken(text: CharSequence): CharSequence {
                val i = text.length

                return if (i > 0 && text[i - 1] == ' ') {
                    text
                } else {
                    if (text is Spanned) {
                        val sp = SpannableString("$text ")
                        TextUtils.copySpansFrom(
                            text as Spanned?, 0, text.length,
                            Any::class.java, sp, 0
                        )
                        sp
                    } else {
                        "$text "
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```