# Autocomplete for the whole text view

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm very new to android and I'm trying to do the following. Provide some word completion for the sentence.

Here is the code I have for it:

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
    "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
};

// In the onCreate method
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_country);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where it automatically pop up when user types `Belgium`. But the problem I face is, when the user type this sentence:

```
Belgium France
```

for the first word `Belgium` the pop up comes, when I type `France` autocompletion doesnt work. Why?

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can only use it for one word!, unless you define your own adapter

Comment: Any example for own adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html) for multiple words

[Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/autocompletetextview/android-auto-complete-example/) is a good example of that

Comma is the default separator for MultiAutoComplete, you can set it to space delimiter, please have a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/OrsN2xRpDmA) post to achieve that.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482981/how-to-replace-the-comma-with-a-space-when-i-use-the-multiautocompletetextview) post to for space delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `"Belgium France"`, but you don't have this item in your list (in one `String` object). You will have to create custom Adapter which implements `Filterable` with custom `Filter`.