# MultiAutoCompleteTextView strings getting "," after selecting string from drop down?

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

i integrated  `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` in to my dictionary app so now after integrating it.

i got a problem like this as show in second screen shot...

so now i don't want that ","

as show in second screen shots after !

i am getting "," like this

> !,

plz help me 
thank q

[image]

[image]

```
String[] str={"!","\"","#","$","$1","%","'","+",",","/"};

            MultiAutoCompleteTextView mt=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);

            mt.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

            ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str);

            mt.setThreshold(1);
            mt.setAdapter(adp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is coming from `CommaTokenizer()` called in this line `mt.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());`

To remove the comma you need to implement your own Tokenizer. This is an example:

```
public class SpaceTokenizer implements Tokenizer {

public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
int i = cursor;

while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ') {
    i--;
}
while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
    i++;
}

return i;
}

public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
int i = cursor;
int len = text.length();

while (i < len) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        return i;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}

return len;
}

public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
int i = text.length();

while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
    i--;
}

if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
    return text;
} else {
    if (text instanceof Spanned) {
        SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
        TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                Object.class, sp, 0);
        return sp;
    } else {
        return text + " ";
    }
}
}
}
```

PS: I copied the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596652/4224337)

Comment: thankq for this answer, it is working for me but i dont need space also after that string.

Comment: you can just replace the space by an empty string ( " " to "")